# Automating IBM RTC with UFT

Tags: hp-uft, rtc

we are creating tasks and linking them with parents in IBM RTC. we automated this process through RTC. There is a drop down arrow from which we select an option to set the parent.

The problem is the script clicking drop down arrow correctly for first 2 times in a loop and the 3rd time it is unable to identify the arrow.

Please suggest a solution for this.

Comment: Can you add some more details or code from the script?

Comment: Please find my code snipppet below


Browser("Login").Page("Login").WebElement("class:dijitReset dijitMenuItemLabel","html tag:=TD","innertext=Set Parent")